# Looking to try Autofac with .NET 2.0. What version should I use?

Tags: .net-2.0, autofac

Looking at the deprecated downloads for Autofac out at code.google.com, I see:

Release 1.3.2 for .NET 2.0 (released Oct 2008)

Is this my best option? Is documentation still available for this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heard from Nicholas Blumhardt in the Autofac google group. He recommended 1.3.